# External javascript and css bundles don't load over https

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundler, html5-appcache

I am creating a prototype app at this url:

https://chirobyte.azurewebsites.net

It's a single page app. I am also using a bundler to minify and bundle my css and javascript files:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mustache")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
```

Everything works fine in IE But if I try to load the page in Chrome, the very first time it loads, it is fine. But if I refresh it, I get some strange errors in Chrome. This is a screenshot of the errors I am getting:

[image]

There is no information with these errors. All I see under the status is "(failed)". The response is blank, and the preview is blank. The strange thing is that if I take any of these urls listed above, and copy/paste them into the address bar in Chrome, the content comes up just fine without any errors.

One thing to note here too - I just started to add my cache manifest file (https://chirobyte.azurewebsites.net/manifest/appcache). I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it or not. The timing of these errors seems to coincide with me putting that in there. But even if I take the cache manifest out completely, it still gives me these errors.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. The errors give me no information whatsoever. Am I doing something wrong with the bundling? Or could my cache manifest have something to do with it?

Thanks

p.s. - Just so you can see it, here is a screenshot from IE using the same url from above:
[image]

Comment: Can you verify you aren't (by accident) filtering the chrome logs?.. i suggest you troubleshoot this in Firefox too.. the latest Firefox has pretty nifty debugging tools IMHO. Perhaps you could see it there.